# Error while trying to run Terraform in GitHub Actions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, github-actions

I'm planning to use GitHub Actions to run some Terraform commands on my project.
The workflow is quite simple, it's basically: 
Configure credentials to GCP -> `terraform fmt` -> `terraform init` -> `terraform validate` and finally `terraform plan`.
It fails in the `plan` step, stating that an error occurred while trying to read the existing resource on GCP due to a timeout.

Here's the error message:

```
Error: Error reading ComputeNetwork "REDACTED_RESOURCE": Get https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/REDACTED_PROJECT/global/networks/REDACTED_RESOURCE?alt=json: Get http://169.254.169.254/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/token?scopes=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcompute%2Chttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcloud-platform%2Chttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fndev.clouddns.readwrite%2Chttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdevstorage.full_control: dial tcp 169.254.169.254:80: i/o timeout
```

I'm able to run `terraform plan` locally just fine.

The Terraform version used is 0.12.4 and Google Provider is 2.11.

Comment: Provide your terraform file, to have more validate.

Comment: How are you providing GCP credentials to your GitHub action?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I'm using GitHub Action for Google Cloud SDK auth with my service credentials encrypted using base64.

Comment: @InderRSingh the code runs fine on my local machine, but here it goes:
https://gist.github.com/brunopadz/d26a7c0f48ac978e10f73f93420134fd